# Why Won't My Array Sort? (Visual Basic)

Tags: arrays, vb.net, sorting

I'm working on a project, for school, that reads text from a .txt file to an array.  After doing that, I'm supposed to sort the array, alphabetically, and then list the contents in a listbox.  Here is my code:

```
Imports System.IO
Public Class Form1
'Allow array to be accessed by the entire program

Public books(1) As String
Private Sub btnView_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnView.Click
    'Declare variables

    Dim sr As New StreamReader("C:\Users\Bryson\Desktop\BooksinStock.txt")
    Dim book As String
    Dim i As Integer = 0
    'Establish loop to read contents of the text file into the array and list the array in the listbox
    'the sr.Peek = -1 simply means that the reader has reached the end of the file and there is nothing more to be read

    Do Until sr.Peek = -1
        book = sr.ReadLine()
        'ReDim allows the array to grow with the set amount of books in text file

        ReDim books(books.Length + 1)
        books(i) = book
        i += 1
    Loop
    Array.Sort(books)
    lstBoxInventory.Items.Add(books(i))


End Sub
End Class
```

However, when I run the program, I receive an error on the lstBoxInventory.Items.Add(books(i)) line that says "an unhandled exception of the type 'System.ArgumentNullException' occurred in System.Windows.Forms.Dll

I've tried to lay the code out in various ways to get the sort to work but keep coming up short.  Does anyone know how to get rid of this null error?

Comment: Because you've incremented `i` beyond the index range. Look closely.

Comment: a) get rid of the array and use a `List(of String)` , b)  after the loop `i` is always one increment larger than the array/list and c) it looks like you are just trying to add the last one?  maybe .AddRange is what you want?

Comment: @ShashwatBlack I'm not sure how to change the i being indexed beyond the range.  Where/how would I change the increment to allow the sorting?

Comment: @Plutonix  I can't get rid of the array.  This is for a school project, so I have to follow their rules.  I'm trying to figure out your last two suggestions but I'm new to programming so it will take time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happening because "i" is larger than the highest index

```
    Do Until sr.Peek = -1
    book = sr.ReadLine()

    ReDim books(books.Length + 1)
    books(i) = book
    i += 1 'This is adding 1 to the very end 
Loop
Array.Sort(books)
lstBoxInventory.Items.Add(books(i)) 'When the items are being added it is trying to add an extra i that does not exist
```

**edit**

Honestly I would change the format to use ReadAllLines and list(of String)

Something like (Im writing code from memory)

```
Dim bookList as new List(of String)
Dim bookTextFile as String() = File.ReadAllLines("C:\booklist.txt")

for each book as String in bookTextFile
   bookList.add(book) 
next

bookList.Sort
```

**Edit Again**

Just using this

```
Dim bookList As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Bryson\Desktop\BooksinStock.txt")
```

creates a single dimension array ..

Strings() are single Arrays String(,) are two dimensional Arrays

Honestly your whole homework could be

```
Dim bookList As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Bryson\Desktop\BooksinStock.txt")
Array.Sort(BookList)
```

boom - done.

Test it using

```
for each book as String in BookList
     Msgbox(book)
next
```

You could do

```
        Dim bookList As String() = System.IO.File.ReadAllLines("C:\Users\Bryson\Desktop\BooksinStock.txt")
    Dim books(bookList.Length - 1) As String 'This is the same as ReDim

    For x As Integer = 0 To bookList.Length - 1
        books(x) = bookList(x) 
    Next
    Array.Sort(books)
```

but you would literally be saying bookList = books

But.... if you just want to get your code working, just try this

```
lstBoxInventory.Items.Add(books(i -1)) 'This takes away the extra i that you added
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  From what I'm gathering from everyone is that, the increment is a problem because it is at the end of the loop.  So, would I put the increment in a different location like:

    i += 1
    books(i) = book

Comment: If you have to do it with a streamreader - then you can make "i = -1" and then do "i += 1" right under "sr.peek"

Comment: Part of the issue is I have to keep the array because this is a school project.  Otherwise, I would use a List(of String).

Comment: If you dont have to use the streamreader though, use the ReadAllLines and then you can just do "for x as integer = 0 to BookList.length - 1" and get rid of i completely

Comment: Just a note, I can get the array to list the contents of the txt file **before** I put the sort function in.  It's after the 'Array.sort(books)' that I receive the null error.

Comment: @Nefarri  In regards to your comment about the streamreader, I don't have to use it.  Where I'm confused by your example, though, is where the array comes in?  I have to use it in this assignment

Comment: ReadAllLines will automatically read the whole text file into an Array. You honestly could cut down all your code to two lines. There is no need to use a StreamReader when .Net does all the work for you

Comment: Thank you so much for explaining what the ReadAllLines was for and for taking all of that time with me!  Now the program and code are working to the requirements that I need them to!

Comment: Absolutely man, we all start somewhere - and Im happy to have answered your first question : )